# Display final docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When using multiple docker compose files, they will be merged into a final compose final before it will be used.

Is there any way of displaying this "final" compose file, to see how the different compose files are put together? I am looking for a `dump` command, instead of the usual `up`, `stop`, ... commands, but I do not find that in the documentation.

Is there any workaround for achieving the same result?

Comment: The question is why you want to merge the docker-compose files into one. Obvious reason might be that you want to 'talk' to other services by their service-name. But if you us an external network and give each service an ip address in that network, you can have different services talking to each other without the need of having them in 1 docker-compose file.

Answer (score 4):

The command you are looking for is `docker-compose config`. Pass the same parameters you would to up/stop/etc to parse multiple files, and it will output the parsed and merged yaml with variables expanded.

See the docs for more details: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/config/